# Rigid transformation and similarity transformation in MLS

Tags: least-squares, rigid-transformation

I am reading the paper **Image Deformation Using Moving Least Squares** of Schaefer. I attach the link below:
https://people.engr.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/mls.pdf

In Section 2.3 Rigid Deformations, I am stuck at the calculation of the constant $\mu_r$ in $M$. Anyone knows how to use the Theorem 2.1 to get $M$ and $\mu_r$?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.